# Windows was unable to install your Android

Tags: android, eclipse, installation

I am trying to debug my app in Eclipse on a Kitkat device through Windows 7. 
I wasted all day. I tried everything: USB Debugging, MTP is on.

I opened Device Manager, saw Other Devices, Android, but a yellow exclamation mark is showing.

I tried to update driver software. I browsed to Google USB driver location in my c: drive... usb_driver, and I always get this message:

**Windows was unable to install your Android**

I can see the files on USB, but I cannot debug. My device is not shown in Eclipse Device Chooser.

What does this message mean?

Comment: Consider of dual-boot with Linux system like Ubuntu - you avoid many problems with Android Development. Notice that Android is Linux-based

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have the correct drivers specific to your device installed for adb to work. These are not the Google USB drivers you are trying to install. Search android adb drivers for your device and install them.